# FieldsPlugin onCustomFieldsPrepareDom $field on save different on front and backend

Tags: development, plugin, administrator, custom-field, front-end

I currently develop a FieldPlugin for myself. I noticed some things and don't understand them fully right now. My plugin works in the backend perfect, but raises errors on the frontend, so I did some investigating.

How I've done things until now also might be not the right path.

First fact why my plugin worked until now: If you're hitting the Save button in article edit the method `onCustomFieldsPrepareDom($field, DOMElement $parent, JForm $form)` gets called.

In this method, I saved `$field->value` in a member variable for usage in `onContentBeforeSave($context, $item, $isNew, $data = array())`.  (Yes, this is the part where I think I used the wrong way.)

But what I don't understand is why, in this action, the variable `$field` has different values in the front and backend.

In frontend:

```
stdClass Object (
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Fileupload
    [name] => fileupload
    [checked_out] => 0
    [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [note] => 
    [state] => 1
    [access] => 1
    [created_time] => 2019-07-14 16:25:05
    [created_user_id] => 478
    [ordering] => 0
    [language] => *
    [fieldparams] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object (
        [data:protected] => stdClass Object (
            [savePath] => /images/fileupload 
            [downloadProtection] => 1
        )
        [initialized:protected] => 1
        [separator] => .
    )
    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object (
        [data:protected] => stdClass Object (
            [hint] => 
            [class] => 
            [label_class] => 
            [show_on] => 
            [render_class] => 
            [showlabel] => 1 
            [label_render_class] => 
            [display] => 2 
            [layout] => 
            [display_readonly] => 2
        )
        [initialized:protected] => 1
        [separator] => .
    )
    [type] => jtfileupload 
    [default_value] => 
    [context] => com_content.article 
    [group_id] => 0 
    [label] => Fileupload 
    [description] => 
    [required] => 0 
    [language_title] => 
    [language_image] => 
    [editor] => 
    [access_level] => Public 
    [author_name] => Super User 
    [group_title] => 
    [group_access] => 
    [group_state] => 
    [group_note] =>
)
```

In backend:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [title] => Fileupload 
    [name] => fileupload 
    [checked_out] => 0 
    [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
    [note] => 
    [state] => 1 
    [access] => 1 
    [created_time] => 2019-07-14 16:25:05 
    [created_user_id] => 478 
    [ordering] => 0 
    [language] => * 
    [fieldparams] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object ( 
        [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( 
            [savePath] => /images/fileupload 
            [downloadProtection] => 1 
        )
        [initialized:protected] => 1 
        [separator] => . 
    )
    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object ( 
        [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( 
            [hint] => 
            [class] => 
            [label_class] => 
            [show_on] => 
            [render_class] => 
            [showlabel] => 1 
            [label_render_class] => 
            [display] => 2 
            [layout] => 
            [display_readonly] => 2 
        ) 
        [initialized:protected] => 1 
        [separator] => . 
    )
    [type] => jtfileupload 
    [default_value] => 
    [context] => com_content.article 
    [group_id] => 0 
    [label] => Fileupload 
    [description] => 
    [required] => 0 
    [language_title] => 
    [language_image] => 
    [editor] => 
    [access_level] => Public 
    [author_name] => Super User 
    [group_title] => 
    [group_access] => 
    [group_state] => 
    [group_note] => 
    [value] => 2019_Kreismeisterschaft_Vaihingen_1807016968.pdf 
    [rawvalue] => 2019_Kreismeisterschaft_Vaihingen_1807016968.pdf 
)
```

So why exists in the object in backend the part `value` and `rawvalue` and in front end not?

Edit: I created a tag if someone wants to look into the code and test it on his own. https://github.com/JoomTools/plg_fields_jtfileupload/tree/JoomlaExchange

Comment: where do you check your variable (in the backend)? Before saving in database of after saving in database? I mean, are you sure, your value (value, rawvalue) is stored in database? Is it loaded when you save the items? When your value (value, rawvalue) is stored in database, are you sure that the place in frontend loads it? Is there standard load of items or some customized which loads standard values including your newly created values?

Comment: @Phoca I have moved your "answer" to a comment (where it belongs). Please take the [tour] and try to earn 41 more rep at SO, so that you get an instant +100 rep here and the privileges that come with it.  I am referring to the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/352329).

Comment: @Phoca yes it is stored. If I load the article and go to edit in frontend, value and rawvalue are in the object. If I then press save and look into the object, value and rawvalue are not in there. I don't know if it is a bug or sec feature to hide those two values. I check the same object in front and backend before, onsave and after save.